# Are there any hazards spraying de-Icing fluid on the windscreen?

Tags: winter, windshield

I have recently moved to a colder part of the country where temperatures below -10°C are quite normal. So far I have observed that people only use ice scrapers. Though I spray de-icing fluid on my windscreen (careful not to get any on paint) and it is much more convenient as one would expect. Knowing that de-icers contain IPA (isopropyl alcohol) am I damaging something? What am I missing here?

Answer (score 2):

Spray-on deicing products tend to be fairly expensive but they can be used without causing damage.

Be careful spraying about an open flame as it is quite flammable.

Comment: ... and don't use it on the inside of the windscreen to try and keep it from fogging up ... it only makes things worse.

Answer (score 0):

The commercial mixes are diluted, so the freezing point is not very low, especially after they dissolve some ice causing further dilution. I have used straight ethanol ( methanol will dissolve paint); it works well. I put it in the windshield washer reservoir. But don't use it when moving; It dissolves ice but then evaporates so quickly the remaining water refreezes. If the defrosters are on, the ethanol smell is very strong inside. May work better with isopropyl.